# mongodb show dbs listDatabases failed

Tags: mongodb, database

I am new to mongo db.
I just installed mongo DB on my MAC,

After watching this Youtube Video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pWbMrx5rVBE&t=369s

In mongo shell, I entered show dbs and I get wired output.
Kindly help me to understand and solve this

```
> show dbs
2017-09-11T02:45:34.298+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: listDatabases failed:{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "unable to open cursor at URI statistics:table:collection-2-2362555297355466682. reason: No such file or directory",
    "code" : 43,
    "codeName" : "CursorNotFound"
} :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
Mongo.prototype.getDBs@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:62:1
shellHelper.show@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:769:19
shellHelper@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:659:15
@(shellhelp2):1:1
```

Comment: You just installed? Or did you actually copy data from somewhere? And if you copied data, then how exactly did you do that? The collection naming suggests this as its unlikely you "just installed" and decided to create and name a collection in such a way. You get answers here by telling the truth. All the truth.

Comment: I just installed and very new to this mongo db. So dint copy any data.

Comment: Where did the collection come from then? Honestly this suggests a read error which in turn suggests data corruption. If you have honestly "just installed" then there should be nothing wrong with removing the current install, reinstalling and starting again. Everything in your question points to some part of the problem you are not actually telling about. So if you "just installed", then reinstalling will not matter to you, and that is what you should do. Of course when you reinstall, don't copy data files directly and don't post questions omitting any errors that occurred previously.

Comment: Whether u are Running mongod with db path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a couple of research, I found the solution and sharing all I learned so no new learner struggles like me.

**My mistake :**

I was staring mongodb using :

```
mongod --config "c:\MongoDB\Mongod.cfg"
```

and start mongo shell by just running

```
 mongo
```

---

**Starting Mongo DB and Shell**

Then understood, what each command does :

```
|*| Start Mongo DB with default config :

    mongod

|*| Start Mongo DB with config file :

        mongod -f "c:\MongoDB\Mongods.cfg"
    |Or| 
        mongod --config "c:\MongoDB\Mongod.cfg"

|O| Start Mongo DB with config flags :

    mongod --dbpath "c:\mongodb\data\nameMdb" --logpath "c:\mongodb\log\nameMdbLog.log" --directoryperdb --logappend
```

---

So correspondingly we should use mongo also to start shell :

```
|*| Start Mongo shell with default config :

    mongo

|*| Start Mongo shell with localhost config flags :

    mongo --host localhost --port 28888

|*| Start Mongo shell with public config flags and user details :

    mongo --username <user> --password <pass> --host <Host.IP.Adrs> --port 28888
```

|*| Creating Config File is explained here with example :

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/rpm/mongod.conf

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue when configuring MongoDB for replication.

When I run the command below:

```
mongo
show dbs
```

I get the error:

```
> show dbs
uncaught exception: Error: listDatabases failed:{
    "topologyVersion" : {
        "processId" : ObjectId("60ddea05beb1d89d4d139546"),
        "counter" : NumberLong(0)
    },
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "not master and slaveOk=false",
    "code" : 13435,
    "codeName" : "NotPrimaryNoSecondaryOk"
} :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
Mongo.prototype.getDBs/<@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:147:19
Mongo.prototype.getDBs@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:99:12
shellHelper.show@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:937:13
shellHelper@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:819:15
@(shellhelp2):1:1
```

**Here's how I fixed it**:

The issue was that I had enabled the replication feature in the `/etc/mongod.conf` file without initializing the replication, so MongoDB could not tell which replica was the primary replica or secondary replica.

All I had to do was to comment out the replication feature in the `/etc/mongod.conf` file since I was not yet ready to set up replication:

```
#replication
#  replSetName: my-replica-set-name
```

After which I restarted the MongoDB server:

```
sudo systemctl restart mongod
```

This time the command ran fine.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this issue today, installing the latest version of MongoDB with Homebrew and then launching the mongo shell and entering the command "show dbs". I tested this multiple times and spent some time researching it. The symptoms match an issue that was reported here: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-20753 where the issue was described as building WiredTiger separately from MongoDB and using an out of date version of WiredTiger.

While this is not the case for what you and I have experienced (note that Homebrew is currently installing 3.4.9 and WiredTiger 2.9.2), I guessed that it could be a similar mismatch between WiredTiger and MongoDB, so I decided to try installing a different version.

I ended up installing the latest "dev" version using this Homebrew command:

```
brew install mongodb --devel
```

This installs MongoDB 3.5.13 and WiredTiger 3.0.0 which do not have the issue. Note that 3.4.9 was released the day you reported this issue and 3.5.13 was released the next day, although 3.4.9 is still the current community edition listed here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was replSet name.
I was changed my hostname at the Sharing preference and it was different with the previous installed replSet config's host name.

You can see the rs.config() in mongo shell like this.

```
"members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "host" : "MBA.local:27777",
            "arbiterOnly" : false,
            "buildIndexes" : true,
            "hidden" : false,
            "priority" : 1,
            "tags" : {
                
            },
            "slaveDelay" : NumberLong(0),
            "votes" : 1
        }
    ],
```

See the host: section and change it by rs.config({object}) command in mongo shell,
or just add the line below at the /etc/hosts file.

```
127.0.0.1 MBA.local
```